# firebase: deleting data belonging to userId

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Hello Im fairly new to firebase and Im having some issues extracting data. I have two collections in my database: one is for my users and other one for goals. I want to delete all data from a user but when I get to delete data from the goals collection there is no way for me to know what data belongs to them as the id is different from the userId.

This is the issue I'm running into: the id is different for the document from the authorId
[image]

Can someone help me reorganize my data where I don't create a new Document each time I create new goals but instead just adds it to the existing one. This is my code for deleting data and creating new goals

```
const onDeleteAccountPress = () => {
    firebase.database().ref('users/'+userId).remove()
    //firebase.database().ref('goals')
    firebase.auth().currentUser.delete()
    .then(function(){
        props.navigation.navigate('Login');
        props.navigation.reset({ index: 0, routes: [ { name: 'Login' } ] });
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log('there is something wrong')
    })
    
}

useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;

    if (isMounted) {
        loansRef.where('authorID', '==', userId).orderBy('createdAt', 'desc').onSnapshot(
            (querySnapshot) => {
                const newGoals = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    const goal = doc.data();
                    goal.id = doc.id;
                    newGoals.push(goal);
                });
                setCourseGoals(newGoals);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    }
    return () => {
        isMounted = false;
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: The code does not contain any method for creating data in Firestore. Can you add `setCourseGoals` code as well? I suppose it's there.

Comment: @vitooh I will add it right now, thanks for the help

Comment: @vitooh setCourseGoals is a state function so there isn't much code for it